# If statement in Django not working in properly

Tags: python, django

I have a small project and I have been unable to get the following statement to work. Any help would be great. User inputs can either `self.sale_head` which is a $ value,if a $ value is not add a `self.estimated_weight_hd` is used to get the total weight, the code below should return a `estimated_weight_total` which can be used for the total sale price. All works when I add the `estimated_weight_total` manually. I am lost as why.

```
def calc_estimated_weight_total(self):
    if self.sale_head <= 0:
        amount = (self.number * self.estimated_weight_hd)
        return amount

def save(self):
    self.estimated_total_weight = self.calc_estimated_weight_total()
    super(SaleNote, self).save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't do what you want cause if `self.sale_head > 0` nothing will return. From your description, I think your code should be somthing like:

```
def calc_estimated_weight_total(self):
    if self.sale_head <= 0:
        amount = (self.number * self.estimated_weight_hd)
        return amount
    else:
        return something_only_you_know

def save(self):
    self.estimated_total_weight = self.calc_estimated_weight_total()
    super(SaleNote, self).save()
```